# AWS S3 download files with exec permission

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I've been struggling with this one for quite a while. Thought it would work out-of-box based on AWS documentation of supporting the acl header.
I'm using the AWS S3 CLI in order to download files from my S3 bucket. Some of the files will need to have 'exec' permissions (running on Linux).
I can chmod the files but I would like to control that during the upload rather than during the download.

So, the question is whether I can use the AWS CLI so that it will automatically grant execution (or other) permissions based on something that I can set during the upload or afterwards on the uploaded file.

Thanks,

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/how-to-set-default-file-permissions-for-all-folders-files-in-a-directory When you use the AWS CLI I assume the linux VFS creates a file on the linux filesystem, When file is created, it is given with the default mask, change default mask for that directory.

Comment: Hi @Lio Ohana, have you found a solution ? I have the same problem with a public bucket. Update the default mask of the parent directory in not a solution because it is resources for all people